# Pokémon go pokémon escaping

Tags: pokemon-go

Today I started having the following issues in Pokémon GO:

- I can't spin pokéStops and get rewards
- When I catch pokémon, even the lowest CP ones, they escape every time. I've tried using razz berries, that doesn't work. Neither does using great balls.

I do have Internet. I'm not on wifi. I can send messages and browse Internet.

NOTE: I did try to modify my gps location and I was unsuccessful. I only got a pokémon or two and deleted them immediately. I do apologize for trying to hack it but I'm now fully legit.

Comment: Keep in mind that we are not Niantic support, so apologizing to us for spoofing your GPS and trying to cheat the game will not un-ban you. There have also been rampant server issues in the past week, so the games functionality has been screwy at times. You're definitely soft-banned though.

Comment: Can we not close questions as a dup to a closed question?

Answer (score 6):

You're just softbanned for a bit. Wait for 30 minutes to a few hours and you should be able to start capturing pokemon again.

[Source](http://bgr.com/2016/07/15/pokemon-go-cheating-ban/)

Comment: It's perm or not? I need to know because I'm at the beach and wanna catch some pokemons. More information please

Comment: Aside from the fact that I literally said wait for 30 minutes to a few hours? And I posted an article where I got my source from?

Answer (score 2):

This is how they suspend accounts who break the rules, such as GPS Spoofing.  You will still be able to access the game, but unable to collect from pokestops and everything will escape.  I've heard it only lasts an hour or two right now, but can't confirm from experience.  Down the road punishments may get more severe so I would highly recommend playing the game legit.